# What's the difference between reset and reboot?

Tags: reboot, reset

I have a Dedicated Server, there are commands about `reset`, `reboot`.

I don't know what's the difference between them, who can tell me about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPMI interfaces on a BMC typically give you two options to restart your server:

- **reboot**: Send an ACPI command to the server, that instructs the OS to reboot. This is a clean reboot, usually without the need for `fsck` but obviously won't work if the OS is crashed or has no ACPI functionality
- **reset**: Reset the underlying (possibly virtual) hardware. This creates a hard (unclean) reboot with possibly `fsck` or other cleanup necessary. It will work even on a crashed OS though.

Comment: Note that 'reset' often means a full reinstall/redeploy, not necessarily a power control command.

Comment: @grawity Not in an IPMI interface.

Comment: what's the meaning of `clean reboot`'s `clean`?

Comment: @Attie: The OQ said it between the lines :)

Comment: @244boy `clean` means "rebooted in the way the OS intends to be rebooted", as opposed to "crashed"

Comment: to expand: "_reboot_" typically means "_shutdown procedure followed, and relevant caches and buffers written to disk_"... while "_reset_" would have a very similar effect to "_turning off and on again_"

Comment: @Attie do you mean the `turning off and on again` is `power on and off`?

Comment: @EugenRieck: OP didn't mention IPMI at all, and I'd actually be surprised if a dedicated server provider would allow direct IPMI access, instead of a properly secured API or control panel.

Comment: @grawity Obviously this indeed was the solution